# Reusing query with one less join in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, join

Is there any smart way of reusing current query. I want to use same query **EXCEPT** from one join. See example below:

```
 $this->db->distinct();
 $this->db->select('outfit_main.*');
 $this->db->join('outfit_products', 'outfit_main.id = outfit_products.outfit_id');                                       
 $this->db->join('product', 'outfit_products.product_id = product.id'); 
 $this->db->join('favorite', 'favorite.product_id = outfit_products.product_id');
 $check = $this->db->get('outfit_main')->result('OutfitModel');  

if ($check === false) {
    //How to - use above query 
    //EXCEPT from 
    //$this->db->join('favorite', 'favorite.product_id = outfit_products.product_id');

    $check = $this->db->get('outfit_main')->result('OutfitModel');  
}
```

With smart way I mean that I wouldn't have to reset whole query and create a whole new query.

Comment: wrap it in a function that returns results and adjust according to arguments

Comment: Yes, I guess I could wrap it into a function. Thank you.